# easy way to initialize const array

Tags: rust, constants

I hope to define a constant array (`FIBONACCI_SEQUENCE` in this example) to be accessed globally, whose items can be computed with a const function (`fib()` in the case).

When initializing the array, I have to manually type `[fib(0), fib(1), fib(2)...]` til the last one. Is there an easy way to initialize it with something like `[fib(i) for i in 0..200]`?

Fibonacci seqnece is simply an example here, the actually user case is much more complicated.

```rust
pub const fn fib(n: i32) -> i32 {
    if n <= 1 {
        return n;
    }
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

const FIBONACCI_SEQUENCE: [i32; 3] = [fib(0), fib(1), fib(2)];


fn main() {}
```

Comment: Your fibonacci function is faulty: it should be `if n == 0 || n == 1` instead of `if n <= 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is initializing the array with zeros first and then assigning the desired values in a `while` loop:

```
const FIBONACCI_SEQUENCE: [i32; 20] = {
    let mut seq = [0; 20];
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < 20 {
        seq[i] = fib(i as i32);
        i += 1;
    }
    seq
};
```

`for` loops are not yet allowed in const context, but overall it's not too bad.